# MaterialDatePicker How to Change m/d/yy to dd/mm/yyyy in android

Tags: android, materialdatepicker

[image: 1]

MaterialDatePicker How to Change m/d/yy to dd/mm/yyyy in android

`setInputMethod(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_TEXT).` `INPUT_MODE_TEXT` is used when you want the user to manually enter the date. `INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR` is the default input mode when the date picker is launched.

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: Date format is controlled by locale set by user on their phone, not by your app.